# Can the inverse of a matrix without zero entry has zero entry?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

As the title suggests. I tried to think from an operational point of view of square matrix: if some linear transformation maps a set of basis vectors to somewhere not on the original axes, when you want to transform it back, surely none of the initial axes won't lie on the current bases so to the current bases those axes are described by a set of coordinates which does not contain any zero. Is this reasoning right? And is there any other perspective to think about it?

Answer (score 4):

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{array} \right)^{-1}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right).$$

Since you know that $M^{-1}$ is given by

$$M^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det M}\mathrm{Com}(M)^T,$$

you just have to find an invertible matrix with non zero entries and a $0$ minor. Since

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

would be such a minor, complete it to form the desired matrix. It is impossible in the $2\times 2$ case since the minors are (up to sign) the elements of the matrix, so a minor would be $0$ if and only if your matrix has a $0$, which is excluded.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same to ask if a matrix with zero entries can have an inverse without zeros entries. It is impossible for $2 \times 2$ matrices, but after playing around for a bit, I find
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -4 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$